# Adding clickable feautures in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I want to add features to a vector layer and on click on the feature want to display information about it. Can anyone guide me through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display a pop up to show the information.

set the attribute say 'name' which contains the information on your feature as follows,

```
var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(specify your points here),
{some:'data'},
{externalGraphic: 'image for your feature', 
graphicHeight: 21, graphicWidth: 16});
feature.attributes = {
name:"My feature info"};
```

after creating your feature add it your vector layer and set the control as follows

```
Control = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(myvectorLayer,
{
onSelect: onFeatureSelect,
onUnselect: onFeatureUnselect 
});
```

now define your onFeatureSelect function

```
function onFeatureSelect(feature) 
{
var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("MyPopUp",
feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
null,feature.attributes.name, null, true, onPopupClose);
popup.panMapIfOutOfView = true;
popup.autoSize = true;
feature.popup = popup;
map.addPopup(popup);
}
```

the piece of code "feature.attributes.name" would display whatever present in "name" attribute of your feature as body of the popup. You can even define your name attribute in the feature with combination of html tags containing img tag and so.

Comment: thanks a lot. it works. i created 2 features and on click am displaying popup on the map, but the problem is when i click on first feature, pop up appears and when i go on to click second feature the first pop up remains on the map, both popup are shown. i want to remove active pop up before displaying other

Comment: That is because you are not destroying the active pop up before creating a new one. Destroy all the active popup's on the map either while creating a new one or in your onFeatureUnselect function.